# How to drop the rows based on column values whose occurrence is least

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

To drop the rows whose occurrence in column is 1 
Dataset:

```
t={'name':['max','max','colin','roman','roman']}
df=pd.DataFrame(t)
```

The expected output should be :

```
t={'name':['max','max','roman','roman']}
df=pd.DataFrame(t)
```

Could you please look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby and filter:

```
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x:len(x)>1)
```

output:

```
    name
0   max
1   max
3   roman
4   roman
```

if you need to use `value_counts()`:

```
cnt = df['name'].value_counts()
df[df['name'].isin(cnt[cnt>1].index)]
```

Comment: @AvinavSuman Why do you need to use value_count()?

Comment: yeah i got it i was approaching to this problem by using value_count()

Comment: @AvinavSuman added the value_counts() solution. But I would go with the first one. It is more readable and probably faster.

Comment: yes i will also choose the first approach as its more understandable

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using `value_counts` :

```
A = df['name'].value_counts()
df[df['name'].isin(A[A > 1].index)]
```